# How to install Burn app in macOS?

Tags: installation, macos-catalina

I have downloaded a Burn program for optical media on Mac from SourceForge (https://sourceforge.net/projects/burn-osx/): The downloaded ZIP file "burn-3.1.4" contains a folder named "Burn.localized".

How do I install this in Mac? I am completely new to Mac. I have macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19G73).

Comment: Not sure where you got the .localized file from. The download is called burn-3.1.4.zip & should unpack to an app bundle called Burn & a Read Me file called gpl.txt I don't even see a localized file in the app bundle [which you shouldn't open anyway as a regular user]

Comment: OK, in Finder I double-clicked the ZIP file. That extracted the folder "Burn". I dragged this folder to the Apps item in the Finder sidebar. is that correct?

Comment: Yup, that's it. You could have dragged just the app itself, you don't really need the folder. Mac apps will [usually] run from anywhere, but convention is to put them in Applications. It keeps things tidy.

Comment: Thanks for the information.